# Permission is required + infinitive clause

Tags: prepositions, subordinate-clauses

Is there a correct and natural way to construct a sentence starting by "Permission is required" that contains both the action that requires permission and the person who would do the action.

For example, is this correct and natural: **"Permission is required for him to do something"**?

Comment: Yes, that sentence is grammatical and sounds fine. "Permission is required **to** leave the campus during school hours." "Permission is required **for him** to leave the campus." "Permission **from** the principal is required for students to go home early." All good.

Comment: Thank you! This could be an answer if you wanted.

Comment: Where does the 'noun clause' in your title come into it?

Comment: BillJ, please suggest a correct title, a correct term to refer to part of the sentence after 'required'.

Comment: You could put 'Permission is required + infinitival clause'.

Comment: Does infinitival clause include "for him"?

Comment: Yes: "for" is a subordinator introducing the clause, and "him" is the subject. Note that the infinitival clause functions as an adjunct of purpose, cf. "Permission is required **in order** for him to do something".